# Eclipse not Opening

Tags: eclipse, command-prompt, workspace

Actually there us something wrong with my .metadata file I guess, though I am not sure.

But the Problem is that I am not able to Open my Eclipse, when I try it shows the 
" An error has occurred. See the log file ."

This has been happened to me before and I had Created new WorkSpace from Command Prompt, but now I forgot how to do that.

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks
David Brown

Comment: Have you tried looking at the log file?

Comment: Yes, but I could not get what is wrong .

Comment: what does it say? You may want to add the pertinent parts to your question.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\David\myWorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.root\131.tree (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: @David, Do you want to know how to create new workspace without opening eclipse?

Comment: Any reason for creating WS from command line ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the java sdk again thru Eclipse "Install New Software" if possible. 
If not, back up you current copy of eclipse, and reinstall. What version u working on ?

Took me 3 days to find the right version for me. 
Just my thinkings.

AC